# Does the way `as` works in Swift depends on context?

Tags: swift, error-handling, casting

Apple provides the following example [in their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/handling_cocoa_errors_in_swift):

```
do {
    try customThrow()
} catch MyError.specificError1 {
    print("Caught specific error #1")
} catch let error as MyError where error.code == .specificError2 {
    print("Caught specific error #2, ", error.localizedDescription)
    // Prints "Caught specific error #2. A customized error from MyErrorDomain."
} catch let error {
    fatalError("Some other error: \(error)")
}
```

Why does this line work:

```
} catch let error as MyError where error.code == .specificError2 {
```

yet the following line results in `nil`:

```
let e = error as? MyError
```

?

Either `error` can be casted to `MyError` or it cannot, correct? So how can these two lines produce different results? Does the behavior of `as` varies on context and is different in `catch` clauses?

## Update

The linked documentation is about Cocoa errors, that means `NSError` objects. So to reproduce, you'd do something along these lines:

```
extern NSErrorDomain const MyErrorDomain;
typedef NS_ERROR_ENUM(MyErrorDomain, MyError) {
    specificError1 = 0,
    specificError2 = 1
};
```

then you create and pass the error in Obj-C, not in Swift:

```
NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:MyErrorDomain
    code:specificError1 userInfo:nil];

[someObj handleError:error];
```

and in Swift you have:

```
func handleError ( error: NSError ) {
    if let e = error as? MyError {
        // Never happens, never true
    }
}
```

Yet when thrown as an error:

```
- (BOOL)throwError:(NSError **)outError {
    *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:MyErrorDomain
        code:specificError1 userInfo:nil];
    return NO;
}
```

and then caught in Swift, this is supposed to work correctly according to Apple's documentation. And I wonder how this can be.

## Update 2

Following the code path, the error was once passed along as `CFErrorRef`, which is possible thank to toll-free bridging but when the error is converted back to a `NSError`, it won't look the same to Swift anymore.

This is the Swift debugger output when the error was originally created:

```
(lldb) p error
(NSError) $R0 = 0x0000000100606ad0 domain: "MyErrorDomain" - code: 0 {
  _userInfo = 0x00007fff80983090
}
```

And this is the output after it traveled around as a `CFErrorRef` and becomes a `NSError` again:

```
(lldb) p error
(NSError) $R1 = 0x0000000105505360 domain: "MyErrorDomain" - code: 0 {
  ObjectiveC.NSObject = {
    baseNSObject@0 = {
      isa = __SwiftNativeNSError
    }
    _reserved = 0x0000000000000000
    _code = 0
    _domain = 0x0000000100004230 "MyErrorDomain"
    _userInfo = 0x00007fff80983090
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's the same error. Same domain, same code but now it's not castable anymore to `MyError`.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a *self-contained* [mre]?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. At which point exactly is `let e = error as? MyError` called and returns `nil`?

Comment: @MartinR Did you use `NS_ERROR_ENUM` and defined the error in Objective-C, created the error in Objective-C as `NSError` and passed it to Swift code? As that's what the linked documentation is all about (the headline is "Handling Cocoa Errors in Swift" and Cocoa Errors are `NSError` objects)

Comment: I defined `MyErrorDomain` and `MyError` in an Objective-C header file, imported that to Swift, and used the Swift function `customThrow()` as defined in the documentation. – Please add the `let e = error as? MyError` call to your code example.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How can that work? How would Swift know at compile time that the `NSError` it got is castable to a specific Swift error at runtime? If I use `as` the compiler refuses to compile, saying `'NSError' is not convertible to 'MyError'`, which is an expected result.

Comment: In my test program the `catch let error as MyError where error.code == .specificError2 { ... }` block is executed. Inside that block, `let e = error as? MyError` succeeds and does *not* give `nil`. The compiler warns at that place that a “Conditional cast from 'MyError' to 'MyError' always succeeds”

Comment: @MartinR Don't throw the error in Swift, create it in Objective-C and pass it to the Swift code. If you create it in Swift, you get a Swift error and not a wrapped Obj-C error.

Comment: A complete self-contained program would really be helpful.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How do you create an error in Obj-C and catches it in Swift using Playground?

Comment: @MartinR Then I need to create an entire Xcode project which I cannot upload here. I run into this issue in a project that has millions of code lines. Just create the error in Obj-C using `+[NSError errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:]`, pass it to a swift function that takes `error: NSError` as argument and then try to cast it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236106/discussion-between-martin-r-and-mecki).

Comment: @MartinR I don't have time for a live chat right now, I have to go in a minute but I updated the question to clarify the difference.

Comment: I still can not reproduce the problem. We need a [mre]. That should not require  more than 4 files: A Swift file, an Objective-C .h and .m file, and the bridging header.

Comment: Info: you may find more about NSError bridging in Swift here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md

Comment: hm, when you create an error in Obj-C code with `[NSError errorWithDomain:MyErrorDomain
    code:specificError1 userInfo:nil];` the type of the value of this expression will be `NSError` - not `MyError`. I don't think the "as-pattern" in the catch clause `catch let error as MyError ` would return a `MyError` instance. So, I would like to see the actual code and an example project.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper: But it does, I have tested it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, the problem is that Apple does some kind of magic with `NSError` that is lost along the following way:

`ObjC -> C -> Swift -> ObjC -> Swift`

Apparently not all `NSError` are the same to Swift, even though they are to Obj-C.

To pass that error through C, it must be a `CFErrorRef`. To get the error back into Obj-C, it must be a `NSError` again, but the Swift Code retrieves the error as `Unmanaged<CFError>?`.

The code that converted the error back did the following:

```
if let unmanagedError = errorRaw {
    let error = unmanagedError.takeRetainedValue() as Error as NSError
    if error.domain == "..." {
```

Only for specific domains it needs to forward the code Obj-C, hence the double cast, as casting directly to `NSError` is not allowed. The problem is now, if that error is finally given back to Swift code, it cannot be casted to a Swift error any longer, despite having the correct domain and code of such an error.

The actual fix that works is to modify the code above as follows:

```
let cfe = unmanagedError.takeRetainedValue()
let nse = cfe as Error as NSError
let error = NSError(domain: nse.domain,
    code: nse.code, userInfo: nse.userInfo);
if error.domain == "..." {
```

As stupid as this code may seem, it does make a difference to Swift whether the error was casted or re-created, while the Obj-C in between simply won't care as for that code it makes no difference at all.

## Summary

The behavior of `as` does not depend on context but it behaves on more than just types. Unlike a cast in C/Obj-C, the rule that "you either can always cast type A to type B or never do so" does not apply to Swift, since "as" dynamic casting and if a cast is possible at runtime and not can depend on more than just source and destination types.

In case of `NSError` it also depends on property values (`domain` and `code`) and also on the internal representation of the object. While the first fact makes sense, second one does not and IMHO is an implementation quirk of the Swift runtime, as when comparing those two different errors above using `isEqual:`, then they actually are and for equal objects, the same cast rules should apply as equality means these objects are "interchangeable", which they are apparently not if one of them can be successfully casted and the other one not.

Answer (score 2):

"Why does this line work:

`} catch let error as MyError where error.code == .specificError2 {`"

with "work" I assume, why does it compile.

What you are looking at in

"catch `let error as MyError where error.code == .specificError2`" is an

*expression-pattern*

where the `let error as MyError` part is a

*value-binding-pattern* → **let** *pattern*, where *pattern* is a

*as-pattern* → *pattern* **as** *type*

So, that thing is completely defined in the Swift grammar and solved by the compiler.

The `MyError.specificError1` in "catch MyError.specificError1" is an

*expression-pattern*

requiring an overload of the Swift standard library `~=` operator.

So, now given

`let error: Error = ...`

If the pattern matches in the catch clause:

`catch let error as MyError where error.code == .specificError2`

IMHO, the statement

```
let e = error as? MyError
```

should assign `e` a MyError value.

At the OP: if you cannot see this, please provide an example.

**Update:**

Clarification what happens under the hood:

For example in this (contrived) code snippet:

```
switch error {
    case ...
        return ...
    case URLError.notConnectedToInternet:
        return MyError.internal(error)
    default:
        return ...
}
```

The disassembled code gives some insight:

```
    0x102684999 <+217>: callq  0x1026fb79a  
        ; symbol stub for: static Foundation
          .URLError
          .notConnectedToInternet
          .getter :
          Foundation.URLError.Code
    0x10268499e <+222>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rsi
    0x1026849a2 <+226>: movq   -0x40(%rbp), %rcx
    0x1026849a6 <+230>: movq   -0x38(%rbp), %rdi
    0x1026849aa <+234>: movq   %r13, %rdx
    0x1026849ad <+237>: callq  0x1026fb770
        ; symbol stub for: static Foundation.
          _ErrorCodeProtocol.~= infix(τ_0_0, Swift.Error) 
             -> Swift.Bool
    0x1026849b2 <+242>: movq   -0x38(%rbp), %rdi
    0x1026849b6 <+246>: movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rsi
    0x1026849ba <+250>: movb   %al, %cl
    0x1026849bc <+252>: movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax
    0x1026849c0 <+256>: movb   %cl, -0x51(%rbp)
    0x1026849c3 <+259>: callq  *%rax
    0x1026849c5 <+261>: movb   -0x51(%rbp), %al
    0x1026849c8 <+264>: testb  $0x1, %al
    0x1026849ca <+266>: jne    0x1026849ce               ; <+270> at HTTPClient.swift
```

That means, that for system defined NSErrors (many if not all) the
pattern expression in a catch clause

`catch SomeSystemError.specificError1`

resolves calling the infix `~=` operator for the `Code` property type, which is defined in Foundation - if this `Code` type conforms to `_ErrorCodeProtocol`.

Note, the infix operator `~=` will be called by the Swift compiler when performing a pattern match.

**Update 2**

Given the following snippet:

```
            } catch let err as URLError where err.code == URLError.notConnectedToInternet {
                return Error.internal(error)
```

and

```
let e = error as? URLError
```

The disassembled code calls `swift_dynamicCast` in both code snippets. So, there should be no difference in the expression result IFF the type given as parameter (here `URLError`) for the dynamic cast call is the same (which I think is given in OPs example).

Comment: If the error is created in Objective-C as `[NSError errorWithDomain:MyErrorDomain code:specificError1 userInfo:nil]` and passed to Swift then `catch MyError.specificError1` *does* match, without an overload of the `~=` operator. I assume this is some built-in interoperability between Objective-C and Swift errors.

Comment: @MartinR The infix operator is defined. For example for the URLError it's in Foundation: ```symbol stub for: static Foundation._ErrorCodeProtocol.~= infix(τ_0_0, Swift.Error) -> Swift.Bool```

Comment: @MartinR I guess, the "magic" happens when a custom (or system defined NSError) conforms it's `Code` to `_ErrorCodeProtocol`. For example: ```enum ASAuthorizationError.Code : Int, _ErrorCodeProtocol```

Comment: My problem is that I cannot reproduce the effect described in the question, can you? OP claims that a conditional cast `if let e = error as? MyError` fails, whereas the pattern matching `catch let error as MyError` succeeds. To be honest, I don't see how your answer explains that difference.

Comment: It does not, because I think there is no difference in case of `catch let error as MyError`. IMHO, there should be no difference and I cannot reproduce it. My answer focusses on the question if there is a "different context when using `as`". Well yes, there is, it's a "pattern-expression" not an "expression" - but it should (IMO) resolve to the same result.

Comment: @MartinR  Info: in the catch clause `let error as MyError`,  `swift_dynamicCast` will be called, where as in `error as? URLError`, `swift_dynamicCast` will be called as well. So, there seems to be no difference. Also, we need to ensue the symbol name of the NSError is as expected (namespace?).

It would be interesting to see, how the NSError is defined and how it is used/created.

Comment: As I understand it from the question, the error is defined as `typedef NS_ERROR_ENUM(MyErrorDomain, MyError)` in an Objective-C header file, created with `[NSError errorWithDomain:code:userInfo:]` in Objective-C, and then passed to a Swift method `func handleError ( error: NSError )` called from Objective-C. I have tried all that and can not reproduce the issue. I hope that OP will eventually post a complete self-contained program to demonstrate the problem. Until then I am voting to close the question (“needs debugging details”).

Comment: @MartinR Yes, agree for closing. However, when there is an issue as described, it would be a very interesting one ;)